# How to apply selenium in a data scraping code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have this code that looks for the 'See_more' button but despite the html element being correct it doesn't work. Selenium opens the url but doesn't click the button

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

lista_noticias = []

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.globo.com/busca/?q=Seguran%C3%A7a%20da%20Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o'
navegador.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        botao_veja_mais = navegador.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div/a')
        botao_veja_mais.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Clicou em 'Veja mais'.")
    except:
        print("Não há mais botões 'Veja mais'.")
        break
site = BeautifulSoup(navegador.page_source, 'html.parser')

div_noticia = site.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'widget widget--card widget--info'})   

for noticia in div_noticia:
    titulo = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class':'widget--info__title product-color'}).text
    link = noticia.find('a')['href']
    site_publicacao = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class':'widget--info__header'}).text
    subtitulo = noticia.find('p', attrs={'class':'widget--info__description'}).text
    data_publicacao = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class': 'widget--info__meta'}).text
    
    # Criar uma lista de listas
    lista_noticias.append([titulo, link, site_publicacao, subtitulo, data_publicacao])

# Criar DataFrame
noticias = pd.DataFrame(lista_noticias, columns=['titulo', 'link', 'site_publicacao', 'subtitulo', 'data_publicacao'])

# Salvar o DataFrame como um arquivo JSON na mesma pasta do código
nome_arquivo = "noticias.json"
caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), nome_arquivo)

noticias.to_json(caminho_arquivo, orient='records', lines=True)

print("Arquivo JSON salvo:", caminho_arquivo)

navegador.quit()  # Fechar o navegador ao final do processo
```

When the extract is done on the homepage only, everything runs correctly, which leads me to believe that how selenium is being applied is the problem. The package is installed correctly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

lista_noticias = []

navegador = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.globo.com/busca/?q=Seguran%C3%A7a%20da%20Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o'
navegador.get(url)

site = BeautifulSoup(navegador.page_source, 'html.parser')
#print(site.prettify())

div_noticia = site.find_all('li', attrs={'class':'widget widget--card widget--info'})   

for noticia in div_noticia:

    titulo = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class':'widget--info__title product-color'}).text
    link = noticia.find('a')['href']
    site_publicacao = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class':'widget--info__header'}).text
    subtitulo = noticia.find('p', attrs={'class':'widget--info__description'}).text
    data_publicacao = noticia.find('div', attrs={'class': 'widget--info__meta'}).text
    
    #criei um lista de listas
    lista_noticias.append([titulo,link,site_publicacao,subtitulo,data_publicacao])

noticias = pd.DataFrame(lista_noticias, columns=['titulo', 'link', 'site_publicacao','subtitulo','data_publicacao'])

# Salvar o DataFrame como um arquivo JSON na mesma pasta do código
nome_arquivo = "noticias.json"
caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), nome_arquivo)

noticias.to_json(caminho_arquivo, orient='records', lines=True)

print("Arquivo JSON salvo:", caminho_arquivo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use their pagination Ajax API to get the pages, for example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_page(pg):
    api_url = "https://www.globo.com/busca/"
    params = {"q": "Segurança da Informação", "page": pg, "ajax": "1"}

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

    lista_noticias = []
    div_noticia = soup.find_all(
        "li", attrs={"class": "widget widget--card widget--info"}
    )

    for noticia in div_noticia:
        titulo = noticia.find(
            "div", attrs={"class": "widget--info__title product-color"}
        ).get_text(strip=True)
        link = noticia.find("a")["href"]
        site_publicacao = noticia.find(
            "div", attrs={"class": "widget--info__header"}
        ).get_text(strip=True)
        subtitulo = noticia.find(
            "p", attrs={"class": "widget--info__description"}
        ).get_text(strip=True)
        data_publicacao = noticia.find(
            "div", attrs={"class": "widget--info__meta"}
        ).get_text(strip=True)

        # Criar uma lista de listas
        lista_noticias.append(
            [titulo, link, site_publicacao, subtitulo, data_publicacao]
        )

    # Criar DataFrame
    noticias = pd.DataFrame(
        lista_noticias,
        columns=["titulo", "link", "site_publicacao", "subtitulo", "data_publicacao"],
    )

    return noticias


all_dfs = []
for pg in range(1, 4):           # <-- increase the page numbers here
    all_dfs.append(get_page(pg))

out = pd.concat(all_dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(out.tail()) # print just the tail of final dataframe
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                                titulo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   link                       site_publicacao                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               subtitulo   data_publicacao
38       FICE 2021: Para aumentar segurança da informação, Jaya Baloo propõe inovação sustentável e ‘ciberresiliência’           //www.globo.com/busca/click?q=Seguran%C3%A7a+da+Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&p=41&r=1691696717898&u=https%3A%2F%2Frevistapegn.globo.com%2FFICE%2Fnoticia%2F2021%2F10%2Ffice-2021-para-aumentar-seguranca-da-informacao-jaya-baloo-propoe-inovacao-sustentavel-e-ciberresiliencia.html&syn=False&key=b78d6a15c73000f0c459eb45c17c2140  Pequenas Empresas e Grandes Negócios    ... desegurançadainformaçãoda Avast, mostra o tamanho do risco enfrentado por corporações e governos na nova era digital.\n\n\tJaya Baloo...—..., a menos que você proteja suasegurança, privacidade e liberdade de expressão”, afirma.\n\n\tEla defende a inclusão como um fator...  22/10/2021 15h47
39           Na CPI dos Atos Golpistas, Anderson Torres nega que soubesse da gravidade da manifestação de 8 de janeiro    //www.globo.com/busca/click?q=Seguran%C3%A7a+da+Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&p=42&r=1691696717970&u=https%3A%2F%2Fg1.globo.com%2Fjornal-nacional%2Fnoticia%2F2023%2F08%2F08%2Fna-cpi-dos-atos-golpistas-anderson-torres-nega-que-soubesse-da-gravidade-da-manifestacao-de-8-de-janeiro.ghtml&syn=False&key=96cfe8780cc08006649fb97230496a0f                                    G1  ... deSegurançado Distrito Federal prestou depoimento nesta terça-feira (8) à CPI dos Atos Golpistas. Anderson Torres defendeu o plano...—... golpistas do dia 8 de janeiro. Ele era secretário deSegurançaPública do Distrito Federal, mas viajou para os Estados Unidos dois dias...          há 1 dia
40  FICE 2021: Para aumentar segurança da informação, Jaya Baloo propõe inovação sustentável e resiliência cibernética  //www.globo.com/busca/click?q=Seguran%C3%A7a+da+Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&p=43&r=1691696717973&u=https%3A%2F%2Fepocanegocios.globo.com%2FFICE%2Fnoticia%2F2021%2F10%2Ffice-2021-para-aumentar-seguranca-da-informacao-jaya-baloo-propoe-inovacao-sustentavel-e-resiliencia-cibernetica.html&syn=False&key=c8a9f933a7f001cfa772762bd965682e                        Época Negócios           ... usada pela holandesa Jaya Baloo, diretora global desegurançadainformaçãoda Avast, mostra o tamanho do risco enfrentado...—... se sente livre online, a menos que você proteja suasegurança, privacidade e liberdade de expressão”, afirma.\n\n\tEla defende a inclusão...  14/10/2021 21h04
41                             Novo golpe usa inteligência artificial que falsifica vozes e vídeos para pedir dinheiro                                                                                                                                         //www.globo.com/busca/click?q=Seguran%C3%A7a+da+Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&p=44&r=1691696717976&u=https%3A%2F%2Fgloboplay.globo.com%2Fv%2F11677624%2F&syn=False&key=725c6e8038e28fa112a6d1cb64d9b3de                       AL TV 1ª Edição                                                                                                                                                                                                    Especialista emsegurançadainformaçãodetalha golpe e dá dicas sobre como se proteger.  06/06/2023 13h28
42   Justiça autoriza volta de conselheiro investigado por corrupção ao Tribunal de Contas do Estado do Rio de Janeiro         //www.globo.com/busca/click?q=Seguran%C3%A7a+da+Informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o&p=45&r=1691696717980&u=https%3A%2F%2Fextra.globo.com%2Frio%2Fnoticia%2F2023%2F08%2Fjustica-autoriza-volta-de-conselheiro-investigado-por-corrupcao-ao-tribunal-de-contas-do-estado-do-rio-de-janeiro.ghtml&syn=False&key=0ef6722989bd761b524421b1c3e69fc7                                 extra      ... investiga se sobrevivente de ataque que matou Zico Bacana fazia asegurançado ex-parlamentar\nAdvogado de Nolasco, Leo Pedrosa...—... do retorno de Nolasco. Mas que “confirmada ainformação, acatará a decisão judicial e cuidará para que toda a estrutura necessária para...        há 6 horas
```